# DXA Search module - error when publishing one specific page

Tags: dxa, si4t

I have set up a fresh DXA website, and also installed the search module.
I can publish all pages of the DXA website (nothing is customized ,this is a fresh install), and all my pages get indexed in solr.

However, one page consistently fails to publish, due to the following solr error

```
2015-05-29 14:56:56,330 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for transaction: tcm:0-815149-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-815149-66560
at    com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.handleFailure(CommitPhase.java:103) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:87) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:34) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-815149-66560 because of lazy loading error
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:358) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:32) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: lazy loading error
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:554) ~[solr-solrj-4.9.1.jar:4.9.1 1625909 - mike - 2014-09-18 04:09:05]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210) ~[solr-solrj-4.9.1.jar:4.9.1 1625909 - mike - 2014-09-18 04:09:05]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206) ~[solr-solrj-4.9.1.jar:4.9.1 1625909 - mike - 2014-09-18 04:09:05]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124) ~[solr-solrj-4.9.1.jar:4.9.1 1625909 - mike - 2014-09-18 04:09:05]
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexDispatcher.addBinaries(SolrIndexDispatcher.java:184) ~[si4t-solr.jar:na]
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.commitAddBinariesToSolr(SolrIndexer.java:384) ~[si4t-solr.jar:na]
at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.commit(SolrIndexer.java:309) ~[si4t-solr.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:274) ~[si4t.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:189) ~[si4t.jar:na]
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:354) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
... 12 common frames omitted
```

The cause of this issue is something within solr:

```
 org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: lazy loading error
```

This error only occurs with the downloads page (further-information/downloads.html)

Anyone has an idea where i should look to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The downloads page contains PDF multimedia components, so I suspect this is the issue. When setting up Solr to index PDFs there are a lot of additional configuration settings and dependent libraries to add in. Double check your configuration related to binaries in the [DXA docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-09DB266E-ABC6-490A-82CF-2306DF0391F3), in particular for step 8. that the path to the binary extraction libraries (`contrib/extraction/lib`) matches that of your Solr installation.

Comment: This was the problem indeed - in my solrconfig.xml, the path to <lib dir="../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" /> was incorrect. After fixing this, all worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error before. I could be that the SI4T solr schema has a field with an invalid solr field type. You need to change it to string.

Regardless, check your SOLR logs. There should be more info on the root cause in there.